# Trying to import specific data from URL

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets

I am been trying to find a way to import data (price) to my google sheet from pages that seen impossible to do with importxml, such pages for example is:

https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/energy/refined-products/heating-oil.quotes.html

The last price is what im trying to import to my google sheet. unsuccessfully until now, would greatly appreciate your help. thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

disable JS and see if the thing you seek is there:

[image]

native google sheets functions are not able to import JS content